# Modal is not closing on click of Hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

Hi i am try to do basic normal popup using jquery, the issue which i am facing is when i click on first hyperlink its open popup with navigate to different page when i click on the second hyperlink (i.e continue button) its should close the modal and should open the link in different tab. i am using `event.preventDefault()` for the first hyperlink trigger but for the `.continue` class the hyperlink is not working

js

```
function triggerModal(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.continue').attr({'href':$(this).find('a').attr('href'),'target':'_blank'});

        if($(this).hasClass('external')){
            $('#modal, .content').addClass('show');
        }else{
            $('#modal, .content').removeClass('show');
        }
    }

    $('.modal-close, .external').on('click', triggerModal);
```

JSFiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/q2smj9o3/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You don't have `.modal-close` in your `HTML`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani even after doing that my modal get closed but the hyperlink doesn't opens in new tab (ie.when click on continue its should open yahoo site in new tab).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/Lpkt2agz/15/

```
$('.external').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
  $('.continue').attr({'href':$(this).find('a').attr('href'),'target':'_blank'});
    $('#modal').addClass('show');
});

$('.continue').click(function() {
    $('#modal').removeClass('show');
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code,

1. You bound `click` event on `span` instead of `anchor` tag
2. You don't have `modal-close` class in your `HTML`

Here is my version of your code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="external" href="https://yahoo.com">Modal</a>
<div id="modal">
  <a class="modal-close">Close</a>
  <a class="continue">Continue</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function triggerModal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.continue').attr({'href':$(this).attr('href'),'target':'_blank'});

    if($(this).hasClass('external')){
        $('#modal, .content').addClass('show');
    }else{
        $('#modal, .content').removeClass('show');
    }
}

$('.modal-close, .external').on('click', triggerModal);
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/gr8fp3bd/**

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code to control your modals. This code has a few advantages in that it:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lufab6t/1/

- Supports multiple modals
- Uses best practices and targets css that are prefixed by "js"
- Keeps all the JS contained within one event bind
- Keeps the CSS dynamic enough that you don't have to write new CSS for new modals on the page

**HTML**

```
<a data-modallink="mymodal1" href="https://www.google.com">Modal 1</a>
<div data-modal="mymodal1">
    <a class="js-close">Close</a>
    <a class="js-continue">Continue</a>
</div>

<a data-modallink="mymodal2" href="https://www.yahoo.com">Modal 2</a>
<div data-modal="mymodal2">
    <a class="js-close">Close</a>
    <a class="js-continue">Continue</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function triggerModal(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Save variables
  var link = $(this);
  var linkId = link.attr("data-modallink");
  var modalSelector = "[data-modal='" + linkId + "']";
  var continueBtn = $(modalSelector + " .js-continue");
  var closeBtn = $(modalSelector + " .js-close");

  // Update link on continue button
  continueBtn.attr("href", link.attr("href"));
  continueBtn.attr("target", "_blank");

  // Toggle modal css
  $(modalSelector).toggleClass("show");

  // Hide modal under these events
  function hide() {
    $(modalSelector).removeClass("show");
  }
  continueBtn.on("click", hide);
  closeBtn.on("click", hide);
}

$("[data-modallink]").each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).on("click", triggerModal);
});
```

**CSS**

```
[data-modal] {
  display: none;
}

[data-modal].show {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

[data-modal] a {
  color: #fff;
}
```